# How to get only the unique values from a select drop down rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying just to display unique values in the year. This is what I tried so far

```
    =   select_tag("year", options_for_select(Car.all.uniq.map{|c|[c.year, c.year]}))
```

I do know that uniq is for an array. The other thought was to do a validation for uniqueness but the client doesn't want that.

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: The expected output is a dropdown. Which it is but with uniq years. Right now there is duplicated year's.

Comment: Car.all.map{|c|[c.year, c.year]}.uniq ?

Comment: yeah I tried also but didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Here you can use select field to get unique dropdown list, check the below code for help:

```
<%= f.select :year, options_for_select(Car.all.map {|p| [ p.year ]}.uniq,   "Select Year"),:prompt => "Select Year",:required => true %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `uniq` on `Car` model. You should map from the collection all the years, then remove duplicates:

```
= select_tag("year", options_for_select(Car.all.map(&:year).uniq))
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually ended up using pluck rather then map